Monthly or quarterly passenger data for Delhi's airport
I am looking for open access monthly (or quarterly) passenger data for Delhi's international airport (Indira Gandhi International Airport) for the months January 2018 to December 2023. I found data from a wwebsite called CEIC but it's not open access.
Ideally, I'd like monthly data for the period I mentioned. If there aren't, I am happy with quarterly data as well as data for a shortest period (monthly or quarterly from 2019 to 2022).
